# HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I try to use goslate in python 3, the first time it worked but then it gives this error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 5, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Answer (score 2):

Google does not offer a free translation api, the goslate is using a crawler to translate, which is prevented by Google.

The author of goslate has post that and will stop the update.

So the answer is that google has banned your access, so you got a 503.

From: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goslate

Comment: The result of a banned tools is unpredictable, maybe Google Translate accept your request as human the first time, but then find out it's a crawler. That remind me that Google reCaptcha can use one click to find out if you are a bot. but as I said, I don't know exactly how Google block the request.

Comment: So what can be the solution ?

Comment: Many translate APIs are available as paid services, you may use MS Bing Translate API, It has a limited free plan. Or you have to use Google Translate API, paid for it.